# Remove substring between characters in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings and I want to remove everything from `";"` to `"::"` in every object of the list.

For example, I have

```
_ZN8GameMode4tickEv ; Player::tick(void)
```

and I want `Player::` removed. I want

```
_ZN8GameMode4tickEv ; tick(void)
```

How do I do that?

I already tried

```py
inp = [i[i.find(";") + 2 : i.find("::") + 2] for i in inp]
```

but it only give me the things I wanted removed, not the rest that I want to stay.

Comment: Please provide sample input and required output in order to avoid ambiguity

Comment: So I got "_ZN8GameMode4tickEv ; Player::tick(void)" and I want "Player::" removed, the output window gave me "Player::" but I want "_ZN8GameMode4tickEv ; tick(void)"

Comment: Your stated requirement contradicts the required output. You say "remove everything from ';' to '::' " but in your output you retain the space that precedes 'Player'. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

If you know there is only one occurrence of `";"` and `"::"` in your string, this would work since you said you want the semicolon to be kept:

```py
my_string = "_ZN8GameMode4tickEv ; Player::tick(void)"
string1 = my_string.split(";")[0] + "; "
string2 = my_string.split("::")[1]

final_string = string1 + string2
```

The `split()` function transforms a string into an array which contains substrings of the initial string, delimited by a separator you specify (in this case, first ";" then "::").

Comment: Nope, still only gives me " Player"

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer, I understood it backwards

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex. Then you won't have to handle indeces and the like:

```
import re

s = ">_ZN8GameMode4tickEv ; Player::tick(void)"
re.sub(r"; .+?::", "; ", s)
# '>_ZN8GameMode4tickEv ; tick(void)'

.+  # any char (.) one or more times (+)
?   # here: non-greedy (stop at the first opportunity)
```

This [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)stitutes *';' and a space and random stuff followed by '::'* by just *';' and a space*.

Comment: This works for the sample string but relies on the sequence '; ' (semi-colon, space) occurring in the string and I wonder if that's a possible constraint

Comment: Given their desired output where they want the space to stay, I assumed it to be there. Otherwise this is easily modified.

Comment: Please show the easy modification that you refer to

Comment: `re.sub(r";.+?::", ";", s)`

Answer (score 0):

```
string="_ZN8GameMode4tickEv ; Player::tick(void)"

print(string.split(';')[0] + '; ' + string.split('::')[1])

#output
_ZN8GameMode4tickEv ;tick(void)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "_ZN8GameMode4tickEv ; Player::tick(void)"

semiColonIndex = string.index(";")
DoubleColonIndex = string.index(":") + 1

print(string[0:semiColonIndex+1] + " " + string[DoubleColonIndex+1:])
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).